# RJDBC queries against Oracle NUMBER(22,0) fields get wrong results

Tags: r, oracle, jdbc, rjdbc

I have been submitting queries to a particular Oracle database, from R, over RJDBC, for over three years. All that time the results in R seemed to match the results I would get in a database browser (DBeaver in my case).

Now I'm writing queries against a table that has NUMBER(22,0) primary and foreign keys with values in the billions (>1,000,000,000).

**And now** the results in R don't match the results in DBeaver. These data are sensitive, and I haven't figured out a way to illustrate my problem without disclosing the data, nor have I gotten to the point of replicating the problem in an Oracle database of my own creation yet.  I'm open to any suggestions!

A sample query is

```
SELECT
    PK_PATIENT_IDENTIFIER_ID
FROM
    PATIENT_IDENTIFIERS pi1
WHERE
    FK_PATIENT_ID = <SECRET>
ORDER BY
    PK_PATIENT_IDENTIFIER_ID
```

In DBeaver, I get 6 rows with values in the 70,000,000 - 75,000,000 range.

When submitted in R (see below), I get 8 rows with values in the 100,000,000 - 300,000,000 range.

Are my values in the where block getting cast to some semi-compatible type? Do I need to assert somewhere that these are long integers?

```
driver <-
  JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
       classPath = config$oracle.jdbc.path)

con.string <- paste0("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//",
                     config$host,
                     ":",
                     config$port,
                     "/",
                     config$database)

Connection <-
  dbConnect(driver,
            con.string,
            config$user,
            config$pw)

query <- "SELECT
PK_PATIENT_IDENTIFIER_ID
FROM
PATIENT_IDENTIFIERS pi1
WHERE
FK_PATIENT_ID = <SECRET>
ORDER BY
PK_PATIENT_IDENTIFIER_ID"

query.res <- dbGetQuery(Connection, query)
```

Comment: Is `<SECRET>` a number or a character string? If a number, can you give us a rough idea of its magnitude? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks... <SECRET> is an integer. Example: 200000000

Comment: I suspect that you're seeing different tables - i.e. same table name, but in different schemas. Are you connecting to your database using the same username from both DBeaver and R? I suggest that you should fully qualify the name of the table with the schema in which is resides.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica nice catch. I almost always prepend my tables with their schema, but I didn't in this case. Thanks, you have excellent intuition.

Comment: [Don't ask me how I know...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtDdke57Nes) :-)